# Expected Google Glass GPS accuracy

Tags: android, gps, google-glass

I understand that the **Google Glass** is currently equipped with the **SiRFstarIV GSD4e GPS engine**.
Does anyone know the horizontal (for my purposes) accuracy of GPS readings? (i.e. within meters)

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expected accuracy is in all recent GPS chips about 2-3m in 95% of cases.
And like all chips in some cases up to 30m (or more) location error.

I have not tested it, but as long they did not made a horrible GPS antenna design flaw, the value will be very near to that.

Comment: Do you have a source you used? Such a reference could be helpful to me in the long run

Comment: go to the homepage of sirf (the company was renamed some time ago) or ublox, download the product specification. the specified values are only valid under free view to sky = 170 degrees